# Playing a video in MPV triggers Firefox (Web and WebExtensions) to start using 100% CPU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, bug, mpv

To clarify, this is not about playing a video in Firefox. This is when playing *in a completely unrelated media player*.

Specifically, playing a video full-screen in mpv causes Web and WebExtensions processes to start using 100% CPU, and toward the end a "Privileged" process also joins in.

If the video isn't full-screen it doesn't happen. It also doesn't happen with VLC.

Anyone know what might be causing this? Gut says going full-screen is causing a notification to be broadcast, and Firefox isn't handling it correctly, but I don't know if that's really what's going on.

(System is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS / KDE Plasma 5.18.5 / Intel Core i5 M 560, using i915 graphics driver.)

In the CPU usage graph, each block of 100% usage was triggered by opening a video and then going full-screen. In the process table, processes were sorted descending by CPU usage.

Any insights welcome.

CPU usage graph:

[image: CPU usage graph]

Process table:

[image: Process table]